# How to use a Variable in Ansible aws_ec2 plugin

Tags: variables, amazon-ec2, ansible

I want to filter ec2 instances according to the Environment tag which I define when I run the scripts, i.e `ansible-playbook start.yml -e env=dev`

However, it seems that the plugin is not parsing variables. Any idea on how to achieve this task?

my aws_ec2.yml:

```yml
---
  plugin: aws_ec2
  regions:
    - eu-central-1
  filters:
          tag:Secure: 'yes'
          tag:Environment: "{{ env }}"

  hostnames:
    - private-ip-address
  
  strict: False
  groups:
  keyed_groups:
          - key: tags.Function
            separator: ''
```

**Edit**

There is no error message resulting when running the playbook. The only problem that ansible handle the variable exactly as a string `tag:Environment: "{{ env }}"`instead of value `tag:Environment: dev`

Comment: Please add the error message to your post.

Comment: inventory plugins do not honor jinja2 expansions like that; if you require that kind of customization, you'll need a [dynamic inventory script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory-scripts), or have one inventory plugin file per env

Answer (score 0):

This post is already a few years old but since [this still seems to be an issue](https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/issues/688) I want to share our workaround for this:

Before starting the actual pipeline, we generate the inventory plugin file from a template with Ansible itself. After this the inventory will be created by running `ansible-inventory -i aws_ec2.yml ..` etc.

With this approach we don't have to create a new inventory plugin file for each combination and reuse vars for the actual playbooks.

Maybe somebody finds this helpful in the future.